# angular not working with express after adding the files in the server

Tags: html, css, angularjs, express, mean-stack

hello am having a problem with angular not working with express. I had the same problem earlier and it was because i did not add

```
app.use('/', express.static('../client/partials/javascripts'));
```

now i have

My server code is

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var hash = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var localStrategy = require('passport-local' ).Strategy;

// mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mean-auth');

// user schema/model
var User = require('./models/user.js');

// create instance of express
var app = express();

// require routes
var routes = require('./routes/api.js');

// define middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use('/', express.static('../client/partials/javascripts'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// configure passport
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// routes
app.use('/user/', routes);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client', 'index.html'));
});
app.get('/main', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/views', 'index.html'));
});
// error hndlers
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.end(JSON.stringify({
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  }));
});

module.exports = app;
```

my angular code is

```
var app = angular.module('tiks', []);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope){

     $scope.posts = [];
     $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', create_at: ''};

      $scope.post = function(){
        $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
        $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
        $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
  };
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by Express not working with Angular? Are you able to connect with your database on the server? Can you post the error that you are getting?(if there is)

Comment: 10x for your reply am not getting an error message is just that the angular app does not work

Comment: can you help me please as i am a newbie for the mean stack

Comment: You need to tell little more about your problem, or if i can see more code. right now its difficult to figure out the problem, or where to start looking without any more information.